# Is it possible not to translate categories in polylang?

Tags: polylang

I am working on a wordpress website with polylang installed. Polylang seems to translate categories by default. I would like not to translate the categories on my website. Is it possible to do so ?

Thank you,
Olivier

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, you just need to add this code to `/lib/scripts/custom.js` script

```
var origin = window.location.pathname; 

if (origin.indexOf("/en/") >= 0){
     jQuery("a[href='http://blog.prosoftwaresolution.com/category/programacion/']").text('Programming');     
}
```

Be sure to change the JS selector and this string `/en/` by the language that you want to translate.